# Show Html entities like &amp; in report parameter as &

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there an effective and/or fast way to show `Html entities` like `&amp;` or `&euml;` as `&` and `ë` in an report viewer's parameter drop down list?

I have `html` encoded values in the database and now I need to show the original value in parameter drop down list

Or does `MSSQL` have an equivalent for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not loose any performance on the reporting, the users must change these characters in the GUI in order not to see them anymore...

No other suitable solution found for this situation. An mass update on all text columns was an other solution as well, but not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't have a built-in HTML decode function.  Your options as I see it are

1. A series of REPLACEs as long as Earth to Mars
2. A CLR module as a SQL Function (I would use this)
3. Programming change to store another column with the un-encoded html string when inserting

Comment: Tnx. Unfortunatly CLR isn't an option: thanks to SQL Azure. Programming change: Application is converted from PHP/MySQL to .Net and the legacy software stored the values as html entities...

Comment: Extension to #3 - the .Net stores the alternate display column, but your db conversion includes a one-off decode & store